# Error: Could not configure catkin workspace: Cannot load environment from resultspace "/opt/ros/humble"

Tags: cmake, geometry-msgs, ros-humble

I am trying to build a project for that
I am using **Ubuntu 22.04** Linux version.

For ROS-Humble: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

For Catkin-tools: https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

For procedure:  https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

For catkin-workspace:  https://catkintools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html

source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash in .bashrc file

these things I have followed to build and got this error

```
CMake Error at /home/manikanta/catkin_ws/devel/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "geometry_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
    geometry_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

**Error: Could not configure catkin workspace: Cannot load environment from resultspace "/opt/ros/humble" because it does not appear to be a catkin-generated resultspace (missing .catkin marker file).**

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Thank you for updating your question. Unfortunately, it does not help much. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You're installing ROS 2 Humble, but you're following ROS 1 tutorials.

You should clear your workspace and start over following the humble tutorials

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials.html

Comment: Is their any alternative method to configure the catkin workspace, right now I am using this (catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html) procedure

Comment: This is a different question. Please ask it as it's own question with the appropriate background so that others can benefit from the question and potential answers in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!
Please try installing geometry-msgs package using the following command:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-geometry-msgs
```

Comment: I tried this one also ... but no change is output

Comment: Can you please share the output of `ros2 pkg list | grep geometry` ? Is it showing anything?

Comment: geometry2

geometry_msgs

image_geometry

laser_geometry

tf2_geometry_msgs

These are the things I got

Comment: You already have the `geometry_msgs` package. How about cleaning the build space and then re-compile the workspace? Make sure to source the ROS at `opt` as well.

Comment: I have sourced the /opt/ros/humble in .bashrc file..                            but while I type catkin config --extend /opt/ros/humble .. I am getting   **Error: Could not configure catkin workspace: Cannot load environment from resultspace "/opt/ros/humble" because it does not appear to be a catkin-generated resultspace (missing .catkin marker file).**

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a full description of how your have setup your workspace, where and how you have installed and any ROS components. And what setup files you have sourced and what sequence of commands you're running to get the error. The shorter you can describe how to do this the more likely that you'll be able to get an answer to your problem.

Comment: I have edited the content and provided the links I have used. Please look into it once                     Thankyou @Tully for helping me on it

Comment: I'm the future, the actual commands can be very helpful too to get into deeper detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think catkin is no longer available in ROS2.
ROS2 is expected to build with colcon or ament.
Since colcon seems to be similar in usability to catkin, we think you should investigate the use of colcon.